# MULTI TICKETS refunds

Tags: air-travel, refunds

I have flights from London to Japan (BA)  Japan to Taiwan(china airway)Tiawan to Hong Kong (cathay pacific)Hong Kong to London (BA)

The flight to Japan has been cancelled, am I due refunds on the o
ther flights that I can not take?

Answer (score 2):

> am I due refunds on the o ther flights that I can not take

If this is a single ticket/booking then "yes". If these are two separate tickets then "no"

Even if you are legally owned a refund, you are unlikely to get it. Airlines are currently refusing refunds and only given travel vouchers.